Is ConcurrentHashMap needed, if I will only use get() method
I created an enum that includes 4 address formats. I know which country uses which format, and I'm trying to create a HashMap that will include countries as key, and formats as value. I want to get address format of a country with O(1) time complexity.
static final HashMap<String, Format> countries = new HashMap<>();

static {
    for (Format format : Format.values()) {
        for (String country : format.getCountries()) {
            countries.put(country, format);
        }
    }
}

public static Optional<Format> fromCountry(String country) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(countries.get(country));
}

And example Format enum is:
FORMAT1("[num] [road]", ["AD", "AE", "AG", "......", "ZA", "ZM", "ZW"])

My app is multi-threaded, but I won't put any data to this map after the initialization, and I will only get a value from this map using fromCountry() method above. In this case, can I use HashMap or do I need to use ConcurrentHashMap? Is there a better way than using these?

You probably shouldn't, and certainly don't need to, reinvent i18n in Java. Take a look on Google at something like "java internationalization tutorial"

Can i18n handle address formattings?

I'm not sure what you mean by that, but the answer is ... probably ;)

in such case (ignoring the i18n aspect) I would use an unmodifiable map; anyway no concurrentHashMap needed for described use case

Preamble
Not-Invented-Here syndrome?
You're reinventing internationalization. There are a ton of tools out there already. Did you examine them and did you write a few objective reasons to disqualify all popular tools, thus justifying  reinventing that particular wheel? If not, the most correct answer to your specific scenario is 'delete all this and go use one of those libraries'. A simple web search finds all you need.
Note that language i18n is quite different from local custom i18n which is somewhat different from currency i18n. However, i18n libraries can handle all of these.
Bad use of Optional
If you're going to write a custom method for getCountry, returning Optional is rarely appropriate. It's not like the caller is likely to know what to do if your i18n getup has no idea how to do the job for the provided locale.
Methods (and programming in general) is about abstracting and about solving a problem once, and then using that solution everywhere, instead of ad-hoc reimplementing the solution a thousand times all over your code base.
Think of the generally appropriate solution to the scenario of: "I want to look up an address format based on a locale value... (Oh, right I do need to consider what is to happen if this information is not known)" and write it once, here in this method.
I can't imagine Optional is a good solution here. Sure, null isn't much better than Optional - but, there are more options than just 'null' or 'Optional'. Most likely, you should define a standard fallback format and return that in the 'uhoh I do not know' case. Possibly with a logging framework of sorts that registers that an unknown locale was asked for (this framework probably wants to log that only once per unique unknown locale value)
Bad code style
Java has a Locale concept (in java.util); the parameter should presumably be Locale and not String.
Do I need a ConcurrentHashMap here?
Using a plain jane HashMap here is fine. At least, that's likely, it depends on how your code is set up. The key rule is 'Happens Before'. Anytime a line of code writes to any field (and HashMap, naturally, writes to lots of fields when you e.g. call put on it), then whether any other line of code's attempt to read from that field actually ends up seeing the update depends on whether or not a Happens-Before relationship exists between those 2 lines. If yes, the reading code will definitely see it. If not, it may or may not - a JVM is free to toss an evil coin every time to decide.
You want to avoid the evil coin, thus, you want to set up HB relationships. Fortunately:

thread.start() is Happens-Before the first line in that thread. So, if you first fully init your map and then start making threads, all the code in those threads is guaranteed to see the writes.
plain HashMap's .get() call is guaranteed not to write any fields. So, get() on its own cannot conflict with other get calls.

Hence, why it's highly likely you don't need ConcurrentHashMap here - that'd only be the case if you first make all threads and start them, but they will all wait on some signal, then you fill the hashmap, then the threads are signalled to continue. And even that might still work out, if the sending of the signal is Happens-Before the threads receiving this signal, which is likely, but it depends on the signalling mechanism (if it's synchronized, you have Happens-Before, same for j.u.c Locks, so, probably).

I know there are bunch of i18n libs out there, but most of them don't handle address formattings, and the ones that can are overkill for us. Also we are trying to avoid Google libraries, that's the second reason why we are not using a library. The thing I'm trying to do here is not a complete i18n. It's just a simple system that will say if house number should be placed before or after street name.

@HacıEfendi That's.. wrong too. Addresses do not, necessarily, even have the  concept of 'house numbers and street names'. In some locales, it does - and a subset of those prefix the number and others suffix it. But still more locales don't have that at all, or have 2 streets. For example, in the UK, it is quite common to have a house name, and a street name. No number at all. The international standard is 2 strings. Each forming a line - address1 and address2. They can contain anything.

That covers 95%+ of all locales. The rest are impossible to cover. For example, in Dubai, for a while it was common to draw a little map with an arrow pointing at the place the post was addressed to. Unless you intend to shove a png or whatnot in a blob in your db, you can't represent that. Fortunately, address1 and address2 has the advantage of being an international standard.

I'm trying to get an address using a reverse geocoder (getting lat/lng by click on the map), than I'm formatting address components there in the result. As I'm following a specification that has only one address field which has 45 characters limit, I'm trying to build a string like "307 5th Ave, Manhattan" for countries that use USA-like address format, or "C. Artemisa 35, Tlatilco" for countries that use Mexico-like address format. And that's right, not all the countries have all these address components. The system I made is already handling that situation and allows user to write address.
